# Google account on Careers 2.0 not correctly associated with SO account

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I recently tried to log into SO Careers, and I'm having trouble creating my profile via GitHub:

```
Hmm, that email already exists on another account. You will need to log out of your existing account and log back in.
```

This seems weird, considering my SO account (with the email I'm trying to create the profile with) is linked to the Google ID I log in with.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Edit:** The same happens with MyOpenID, for the record.

Comment: I am also having problems with associated accounts http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96076/something-strange-happened-to-the-connected-accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two users for you, an older one with your myopenID and a newer one with your google openID. They interfered with each other. I've merged them and you should be all set.